# which gmail account should be used for requesting registration Id to implement push notification using c2dm?

Tags: android, response, android-c2dm, unauthorized

I am trying to implement push notification in  my android app using c2dm sever.I have used gmail account that is synced in my mobile which is not a Role account(not register with c2dm http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html). and i used curl command

```
curl --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=your_authenticationid" 
"https://android.apis.google.com/c2dm/send" -d registration_id=your_registration 
-d "data.payload=payload" -d collapse_key=0
```

to send the message. but i got response which says Unauthorized as

```
  <HTML>
  <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
 </HEAD>
 <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
  <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
  <H2>Error 401</H2>
  </BODY>
  </HTML>
```

Note i have sign up my android app with another Gmail id like somthing@gmail.com?? should i use somthing@gmail.com to request registration id?

Comment: It should not make a difference which account you use for sign-up and on device, but it is preferred that you dont use the same account for testing and for sign-up. Probably there is a problem with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any of gmail account can be used.It is not necessary that gmail id synced in android mobile should be used for role account.